# How to install Lan driver in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I'm new to Linux and using Ubuntu 14.0. Actually I want to install Lan driver to learn networking with linux but I dont know how to install . I also searched but I didn't understand. So I need your help please help me.

Comment: I believe linux even with the most lightest kernels have LAN drivers included by default to all of possible Network Cards. If there is a problem Try to type at your terminal: > ifconfig eth0 and let me know what is the output.

Answer (score 0):

Normally networking is installed by default. If you want to specifically configure your network settings have a look at the Network Manager (`man NetworkManager`) and ifconfig ('man ifconfig'). Reading the Internet by searching for those topics and by reading the manual pages should give you a good starting point.